# Add video to Access database using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I would like to know how to do to add a video file in the access database using visual.net?

I know how to add video in access using the ole object, however, I want to do this through a form by vb.net

Below is the code I use to add image to the database:

```
 Private Sub btn_Adicionar_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnIncluir.Click
    Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    'cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source=" &  Application.StartupPath & "\Escola.mdb"
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source=D:\Documentos\Escola1.mdb"
    Try
        cn.Open()

        Dim arrImagem() As Byte
        Dim strImagem As String
        Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream

        '
        If Not IsNothing(Me.picFoto.Image) Then
            Me.picFoto.Image.Save(ms, Me.picFoto.Image.RawFormat)
            arrImagem = ms.GetBuffer
            strImagem = "?"
        Else
            arrImagem = Nothing
            strImagem = "NULL"
        End If
        '------------------------<...>---------------

        Dim arrImagem2() As Byte
        Dim strImagem2 As String
        Dim ms2 As New IO.MemoryStream

        '
        If Not IsNothing(Me.PictureBox1.Image) Then
            Me.PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms2, Me.PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
            arrImagem2 = ms2.GetBuffer
            strImagem2 = "?"
        Else
            arrImagem2 = Nothing
            strImagem2 = "NULL"
        End If



        Dim myCmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        myCmd.Connection = cn
        myCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Alunos(nome, imagem, imagem2) " & _
                            " VALUES(?," & strImagem & "," & strImagem2 & ")"

        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue (New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@nome", Convert .ToString (Row ))


        If strImagem = "?" Then
            myCmd.Parameters.Add(strImagem, OleDb.OleDbType.Binary).Value = arrImagem
        End If

        If strImagem2 = "?" Then
            myCmd.Parameters.Add(strImagem2, OleDb.OleDbType.Binary).Value = arrImagem2
        End If


        myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Dados Salvos com sucesso!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Erro" & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Finally
        cn.Close()
    End Try


    CarregaDados()
End Sub
```

The method I use to import the image to be added in the access database is this:

```
 Private Sub label_link_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles lnkProcurar.LinkClicked
    If Me.ofdImagem.ShowDialog = 1 Then
        Me.PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Me.ofdImagem.FileName)
    Else
        Me.PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "/semfoto.jpg")
    End If
End Sub
```

Now I'm looking for a method that saves video in access database through vb.net. In other words a method that allows to add video in access database via vb.net forms

to those who can help me ... Thank you!!!

Comment: Right now, you're taking a picturebox image, writing that to a memorystream, then storing that as binary data in your DB. Do the same with a video file. Read all the bytes from a filestream into a memorystream and the rest is the same.

Comment: You can save anything to a database as binary. You just have to convert it to a `Byte` array. There are various ways of doing that and the best option depends on your starting point. If your starting point is a file then, regardless of the type of file, you can simply call `File.ReadAllBytes` and that returns a `Byte` array.  You could do the same with an image file, but then you'd have no `Image` object to display in a `PictureBox`.

Comment: By the way, you should be calling `ToArray` on the `MemoryStream` in that code rather than `GetBuffer`.  Read the documentation to learn why.

Comment: Also, don't use that silly method of inserting nulls. Just add a parameter every time and if you want to set the field to null then set the parameter value to `DBNull.value`.

Comment: I understood what you wanted to say. But where am I going to upload the video (the image I read from the picturebox), but how about the video how to load the form and then move to the bank?